# Use iptables for forward all but some specific ports

Tags: iptables

I am using port forwarding for VPN (v2ray) from Iran to France. I want use an iranian server for `cpanel`.

Now I want to forward all ports to the french server, but without some ports like 22 80 443 2082 2083 2086 2087 20 21.

The original configuration commands are

```shell
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 37.32.15.82
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT --to-destination 151.80.242.230
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Now where I should put the ports that I don't want to forward, like: 22 80 443 2082 2083 2086 2087 20 21?

Answer (score 0):

Add a rule *before* those rules that looks something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp \
  -m multiport --dports 22,80,443,2082,2083,2086,2087,20,21 \
  -j RETURN
```

The `RETURN` will will stop processing additional rules (and the packet will be handled according to the default policy for the chain).

(You could of course add multiple rules for individual ports rather than using the `multiport` extension.)